# Camera animate from ortho to perspective

Tags: animation, camera

I want to animate a camera from a ortho view to a perspective view.  Is this possible and if so, how.  Seems you can only have one or the other but not both.

Comment: I'm not sure this is possible, at least to have it do so gradually. Perhaps you could utilize a large number for the focal length rather than true orthographicness?

Answer (score 3):

No.

*But*.

You can simulate the effect with a pretty old camera effect made popular by Hitchcock called the Dolly Zoom.

https://gph.is/29cUPJK
(can't embed gifs in SE, turns out)

Another example:
https://i.imgur.com/swqHfwS.gifv

Basically you move the camera forward while cranking the focal size (sometimes called "lens size") back simultaneously (or the inverse for the reverse if you want things to "flatten").  You can animate those controls on the blender camera the same way you can animate most arbitrary properties: by right clicking the value and selecting "add keyframe".

I've also seen people put together driver based camera rigs for these kinds of shots.